# Empty directories missing docker build resulting image

Tags: docker, build

I'm using docker CE 17.06.1 to build a docker image. Everything works so far, except that a directory I created during the RUN command using `mkdir`, won't appear when I take a look at the final image. I also performed a `ls` after creation, to make sure it's really at the expected place. That directory isn't a mount directory or similar - just a simple directory. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Going to have to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Paste your dockerfile